# Is it possible to use the same Nintendo Network ID on two 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

I just bought Pokemon Silver on 3DS, for the Celebi and free theme event.
I am thinking of playing through it, and completing the PokeDex.

If I buy Pokemon Gold and install on another 3DS, using my same Nintendo Network ID, would I be able to play (and trade) Pokemon Silver on one 3DS, and play (and trade) Pokemon Gold on my second 3DS at the same time, using the same Network ID?

Or will I be required to create a new Nintendo Network ID, login to that new ID on my second 3DS, and purchase Gold on that new NNID?

I'm just thinking of a way to trade Pokemon from Gold. Also, from Blue and Red, as I will be purchasing those too.

In summary:
Can I login to the same Nintendo Network ID on two 3DS at the same time, playing different games on the 2 devices, at the same time?

End goal: Complete the Pokemon Silver Pokedex digital copy.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

No, the official Nintendo site explains this below

http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2210/~/can-i-log-into-my-nintendo-network-id-on-a-different-system%3F

The summary is that the NNID are tied to the system.  Two system = two NNID.

Comment: Damn. I guess that's that then. I'll just make a new NNID :)